# Create a new page programmatically in Typo3 version 6.2 or higher?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

What are the possibilities to create a new page programmatically in Typo3? In WordPress there is a convenient function called [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) which can be called by plugins. Is there a similar way of doing this in Typo3? If not, what would be the alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

TCE : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Index.html

in short :

```
$data = array(
    'pages' => array(
        'NEW_1' => array(
            'pid' => 456,
            'title' => 'Title for page 1',
        ),
        'NEW_2' => array(
            'pid' => 456,
            'title' => 'Title for page 2',
        ),
    ) );
```

Comment: Thank you [@rob-ot](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3055478/rob-ot) for your effort to answer. I think this could be the first step, but how do I actually create content programmatically? I'm aware that Typo3 needs tt_content elements associated to the page, but how is it done in the recommended and most elegant way?

Comment: Like posted, you have to use "tcemain" (class ``DataHandler``). First create the pages and then create the content elements. Or you use extbase for this and just use one of the available models. At least for ``pages`` there is one and you can easily create one for ``tt_content`` too.

Comment: if you want to create 'a lot' of new pages at once, use TCE, not extase.